# SQL string to int (date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a field which is of string data type as 'JAN17'. How to convert this to 201701 (int) format?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some sample code, maybe?

Comment: how do you know the difference in the centuries? Is September SEP or SEPT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 2012+ use `try_convert()` rather than `convert()`, just to be safe.

**Example**

```
 Select convert(varchar(6),convert(date,'01'+'JAN17'),112)
```

**Returns**

```
201701
```

Comment: @scsimon I know!  What a great surprise!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti great work, but curious about the format, as [the document says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), default format will be like `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`, how convert function parse the format correctly? and this would work also `Select convert(varchar(6),convert(date,'2001'+'JAN17'),112)` with different format. does that means default option will cover different format?

Comment: @Sphinx Your example would parse as a valid date 2001-01-17.  I suspect the function will look for a 4 digit year, if none, then assumes centrury and the last two digits.  Set DateFormat seems to have no impact.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, hah, just found the document did desribe which format will be supported. the document says:`The default values (0 or 100, 9 or 109, 13 or 113, 20 or 120, and 21 or 121) always return the century (yyyy).`

Comment: @Sandy567 Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the question asks for an INT value..

```
Select convert(int,convert(varchar(6),convert(date,'01'+'JAN17'),112))
```